# Finding the vector potential of a spinning spherical shell with uniform surface charge?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetostatics

I have problem solving the following magneto-static problem. I would greatly appreciate help and guidance.

This is how the problem is stated:

> A spherical shell of radius $R$, carrying a uniform surface charge $\sigma$, is set spinning at a angular velocity $\mathbf{ω}$, see **figure 5.45**. Calculate the vector potential by solving the corresponding partial differential 
>   $\nabla^2 \mathbf{A} = \mu_0\mathbf{J}$.

I have attempted to solve the problem by first writing down what the surface current is, using spherical coordinate system. 
$$
\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r^\prime}) = \sigma \mathbf{v} = \sigma \mathbf{ω} \times \mathbf{ρ} = \sigma\omega r^\prime \sin\theta\:\delta(r^\prime - R)\mathbf{\hat{e}_{\phi}}
$$
where $\mathbf{ρ}$ is the distance from the z-axis, if the z-axis is taken to be the axis of rotation and $\theta$ is the angle measured from the z-axis. From this we conclude that $\mathbf{A}$ only depends on the $A_\phi$ component since the surface current only depends on the phi component, and thus we have $\nabla^2 A_\phi = \mu_0 J_\phi$. And we're left with solving a "simple" **poission equation**. Our problem clearly has **azimuthal symmetry**. We then proceed to solve **Laplace's equation** $\nabla^2 A_{\phi}(r,\theta)=0$. We solve this partial differential equation with help of separation of variables. In the end we find that the general solution is a linear combination of separable solutions.
$$
A_{\phi}(r,\theta)=\sum_{l=0}^\infty \Big(A_lr^l + \frac{B_l}{r^{l+1}}\Big)P_l(\cos\theta)
$$
For the interior region where $(r\leq R), B_l=0$ otherwise the potential would blow up at the origin.
$$
A_{in}(r,\theta)=\sum_{l=0}^\infty A_lr^lP_l(\cos\theta)
$$
In the exterior region $(r\geq R)$ we get that $A_l=0$, because they don't go to zero at infinity.
$$
A_{out}(r,\theta)=\sum_{l=0}^\infty \frac{B_l}{r^{l+1}}P_l(\cos\theta)
$$
We need now to join these to functions together at the boundary $r=R$. The vector potential should be continous at the boundary. So we have the following boundary conditions
$$
\label{eq:one}
A_{out}=A_{in}
$$
$$
\Big( \frac{\partial A_{out}}{\partial r}-\frac{\partial A_{in}}{\partial r}\Big)\Big|_{r=R}=-\mu_0J_{\phi}=-\mu_0\sigma\omega R\sin\theta
$$
From the first boundary condition we find that 
$$
B_l=A_lR^{2l+1}
$$
Plugging it in the second boundary condition equation we get
$$
\sum_{l=0}^\infty(2l+1)A_lR^{l-1}P_l(\cos\theta)=\mu_0\sigma\omega R\sin\theta
$$
Using fouriers trick by multiplying both sides with $P_{l^\prime}(\cos\theta)\sin\theta$ and integrating. We can determine the coefficients $A_l$ since the Legendre polynomials are orthogonal functions, 
$$
\int_0^1 P_{l^\prime}(x)P_l(x)\textrm{d}x = \int_0^\pi P_{l^\prime}(\cos\theta)P_l(\cos\theta)\sin\theta\:\textrm{d}\theta = \frac{2}{2l+1}\delta_{ll^\prime}
$$

$$
A_l= \frac{\mu_0\sigma\omega R}{2R^{l-1}} \int_0^\pi \sin\theta\:P_l(\cos\theta) \sin\theta\:\textrm{d}\theta
$$
This is where I hit a brick wall. I have attempted to solve the problem by expressing $\sin\theta$ in terms of Legendre polynomials and then use the orthogonal condition to determine the coefficients $A_l$. I know that $\sin^2\theta$ can be expressed using Legendre polynomials in the following way. 
$$\sin^2\theta=\frac{2}{3}(P_0(\cos\theta)-P_2(\cos\theta))$$

But if I just want to have $\sin\theta$ I need to take the square root of everything and then it just gets really messy. Where did I go wrong in my solution?

[image: Image of the problem]

Comment: Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6093/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The $\phi$ component of $\nabla^2\mathbf A$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates#Del_formula) is *not* $\nabla^2 A_\phi$, but 
$$ (\nabla^2 \mathbf A)_\phi = \nabla^2A_\phi - \frac{1}{r^2\sin^2\theta} A_\phi + (\text{terms involving $A_r,A_\theta$}) $$

Thus what we need to solve is not a Laplace equation. The solutions are the [associated Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_Legendre_polynomials) $P_l^1(\cos\theta)$:

$$ A_\phi = \sum_{l=1}^\infty \left( A_l r^l + \frac{B_l}{r^{l+1}} \right)P^1_l(\cos\theta). $$

In particular, $P^1_1(\cos\theta)=-\sin\theta$, which should solve your problem neatly.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The laplacian of a vector is $\nabla ^2 \mathbf{A}=\nabla^2 A_r(r,\phi,\theta)\hat{\mathbf{r}} + \nabla^2 A_\phi(r,\phi,\theta)\hat{\mathbf{\phi}}+\nabla^2 A_r\theta(r,\phi,\theta)\hat{\mathbf{\theta}}$. So the phi component of the laplacian of a vector is thus $\nabla^2 A_\phi(r,\phi,\theta)$. Never mind taking a close look at the wikipedia page I see that you're correct! Thank you very much for your help!